# Better way to load scripts and CSS using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I generate some telerik reports on a page which I would like to print when the user clicks "Print". I would like to have a popup window which has the same content as the original report with a print dialog. My current approach is to just copy over the head element using document.write. The problem is that since the head element contains script src which loads external script (and also css loads), when the print dialog appears, the pages are blank. I would like to ensure all the content is loaded first on this new page before print dialog is triggered. How can I do this? Below is my code:

```
function printElem(elem) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=600,width=800');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>' + document.head.innerHTML + '</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.print();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use two stylings? One for print and one for other devices? Then you dont need to make a copy of your document and the user can print dirextly from the browsers print menu

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to build up a page that you'll reveal with `window.open.` You have two options.

First, you could display a loading view that will be hidden once all the other elements have loaded. This is perhaps the most elegant solution if you're committed to opening another popup.

```
<div id="loader"><img src="loading.gif /></div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">Stuff to print</div>
<script>
  <!-- I know jQuery is taboo nowadays, but you get the idea -->
  $(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#pagecontent').show();
  });
</script>
```

Another trick is to write the content and close the window immediately afterward. (I'm not certain if this works on all browsers.)

```
var css = document.getElementById('the-stylesheet');
var content = document.getElementById('the-content');

var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=600,width=800');


mywindow.document.write(content.innerHTML);
mywindow.document.close();
mywindow.document.head.appendChild(css);

css.addEventListener('load', function () {
  mywindow.focus();
  mywindow.print();
});
```

If you're willing to forgo a popup, another trick would be to use print specific styling on the page.

```
<style>
@media print {
  /* Hide everything you don't need here */
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks yes, it's probably better to just have a print dialog directly. The main reason i'm doing it is because I want to hide other stuff that's not needed on the page. I didn't realize that was an option. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onload event on the new window.

```
function printElem(elem) {
    console.log('new window')
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=600,width=800');

    // Add this function here
    function printWindow(){
      console.log('loaded my window');
      mywindow.print();
    } 

    // call it once the new window is loaded.
    mywindow.document.onload = printWindow();

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>' + document.head.innerHTML + '</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    return true;
}
```

It may help..